# Open List or Array of HTTP Link Urls Slowly And Close Tabs or Windows 5 Seconds Later

Tags: bash, url, browser, command-line, text-files

I can open the links with bash, but I can't find a way to open them one by over every 2 seconds and close them at the same interval. I want to be able to watch a screen and look are hundreds of urls freshly opened every so often. I don't care what browser this uses.  Maybe this would work well with an obscure browser which I am happy to use.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the required argument / text file is there 
if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <text_file>"
    exit 1
fi

# Check if file exists
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "Error: Text file '$1' not found."
    exit 1
fi

# open each url from each line of the text file
while read -r link
do
    # Open the link in Google Chrome
    google-chrome "$link" &
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Your problem has two parts: Writing a shell script with delays, and scripting a browser's behavior. The first part is easy (use `sleep`), but afaik Google Chrome is not scriptable in that way. You could switch to a (more) scriptable browser (e.g. [qutebrowser](https://www.qutebrowser.org/)), or move your entire problem into a browser (which you would have to externally start once), write a script (using JavaScript, or PHP, etc.) that shows the contents of the URLs provided, one after another with delays in between.

Comment: @react_or_angluar Did you give my suggestion a try?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a loop that opens one browser at a time and kills the previously opened one after *X* seconds:

```bash
# Read all urls
readarray -t urls < "$filename"   # or "$1" in your case

oldproc=0
while (( 1 )); do
    # loop over all the urls
    for link in "${urls[@]}"; do
        google-chrome "$link" &
        # store the process id of the opened browser:
        newproc=$!
        # sleep a little while the new browser opens:
        sleep 1
        if (( oldproc != 0 )); then
            # kill the old browser:
            kill $oldproc
        fi
        # store the new process id to be able to kill it in the next iteration
        oldproc=$newproc
        # wait for X seconds:
        sleep 4
    done
done
```

I here open the new browser before killing the old because it usually takes a little time to open a new browser. You'll have to trim the timings to your liking.